# cc license attribution implementation

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm building a small website for my parents guest-house and really fell in love your component and would like to use it.

I've looked into the license and saw that attribution must be explicitly placed.

My question is, how can it be done? is a watermark during the slideshow is sufficient enough? what is the common method of attribution?

Thanks

Comment: You should ask the person requesting attribution.

Answer (score 0):

Fancybox v1.3.x is licensed under both [MIT and GPL](http://docs.jquery.com/Licensing) licenses. In short words, just leaving the copyright notice included on the top of the `js` file should be enough.

On the other hand, Fancybox v2.x is distributed in two licenses: [Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/) for non-commercial proyects and a [commercial license in two flavors](http://sites.fastspring.com/fancyapps/product/store) depending on the number of sites you want to use it. In any case, you should always leave the copyright notice included in the downloaded files.

If you are planning to use it in a different way than mentioned above, then [contact](http://fancyapps.com/contact/) directly to the author of the plugin.